Excel: how to calculate average and median for data from each quartile, where data should match specific criteria
Question seems simple but I can not get working formula, already desperate.
I have to calculate gender pay gap. And for it need following:
Imagine column B =gender of employees (male/female), colum C - total remuneration. Need to calculate average and median total remuneration of only male employees in quartile 1 of data. (And then in Q2, Q3, Q4).
By googling I have found some formulas that contain References to values of Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 - it's not correct statistically, as, e.g.employees from Q2 can have same total remuneration as employees in Q1...

Have you checked out functions like maxifs(), countifs() averageifs() ? you can add as many criteria you need.,

I think you will have to help us to answer the question by providing some sample data. I'm not totally clear if you have data for each individual or just some stats.

Can I ask what country this relates to? I started looking at the UK regs and it says you are supposed to try and equalise numbers of males and females in pay levels that cross quartile boundaries but I don't know if that's general

@SolarMike the best result I got so far - e.g., by this formula excel calculates correct average total remuneration of all employees in Q1: =AVERAGE(OFFSET($E$2;1;0;(COUNTA(Table2[Total remuneration])/4);1))
Tried to add one more condition with averageifs - to calculate it only taking employees of specific gender -not successful

@tomsharpe thank you! It's not UK, but something financial institutions in EU  have to report this year to European Banking Authority (first time).

Give a relevant example of the data then we may be able to help. The functions I suggested work well when applied correctly.

Here is a possible formula for Males Q1 assuming you have Let, Filter and Sequence in your version of Excel:
=LET(seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1[#Data])),malesQ1,FILTER(Table1[Pay],(seq<=5)*(Table1[Gender]="M")),AVERAGE(malesQ1))


I will add to my answer later and try to add corrections for when the number of employees is not a multiple of 4 and (more difficult) when the same pay rate goes across quartile boundaries.

Here is a more general formula which will pick out males or females from a given quartile where the number of cases needn't be a multiple of 4 so average or median can be calculated:
=LET(Q,3,gender,"F",
rows,ROWS(Table2[#Data]),
seq,SEQUENCE(rows),
quarter,QUOTIENT(rows,4),
cupper,MIN(MOD(rows,4),Q),
upperLim,Q*quarter+cupper,
clower,MIN(MOD(rows,4),Q-1),
lowerLim,(Q-1)*quarter+clower+1,
FILTER(Table2[Pay],(seq>=lowerLim)*(seq<=upperLim)*(Table2[Gender]=gender)))

e.g. for n=23 Q3 females


Glad it works for you. I have thought a bit about how you would equalise genders across quartiles but not sure if I will manage it very soon. Can certainly add a few notes of explanation.
